# How does type is submit work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

`Type="Submit"` and `type="Button"` in element input. How are they different? When I use `type="button"` then it submits successfully but `type="Submit"` does not? why is that?

```
 <form class="crush-form">
    <div>
        <input class="name" type="text" name="name" required />
        <label for="">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="address" type="text" name="address" required />
        <label for="">Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="lol">
        <input
            type="submit"
            onclick="SubmitClickHandle()"
            name="huhu"
            value="ggg"
        />
        <button onclick="closeDialog()">Close Dialog</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Check this out > https://html.com/attributes/button-type/

Comment: This really depends on what `SubmitClickHandle()` and `closeDialog()` are set up to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a JavaScript function `SubmitClickHandle()` that performs the form submission. If you use `type="submit"`, then the form also submits using the default method, which reloads the page and cancels the `SubmitClickHandle()` code.

You should use `type="button"` when you've provided your own JavaScript to submit the form, and you don't need the default submission.

If you want to use `type="submit"`, the `onclick` code should end with `return false` to prevent the default action:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="SubmitClickHandle(); return false">
```

Comment: Good. What i need to do when i use both type="submit" and form?

Answer (score 0):

Submit buttons trigger the submission of a form (and when they do, their `name` and `value` are included in the submitted form data).

Button buttons don't.

---

> When I use type="button" then it submits successfully but type="Submit" does not? why is that?

Presumably, because your idea of "submits successfully" doesn't involve performing a normal form submission but instead means "Executes the `SubmitClickHandle()` function without leaving the page".

Comment: @Barmar – `type=button` **doesn't** submit forms … no matter what they say.

Comment: It could if the `SubmitClickHandle()` function submits the form.

Comment: @Barmar — Then the form would be submitted by the `SubmitClickHandle()` and not directly by the button.

Comment: Right. And that's the problem he's having -- the two submissions are conflicting with each other.